# How to insert data into database

Tags: php

I have created connection to database and `INSERT INTO` my table does not function properly, `INSERT INTO` my table the VALUES don't have any argument or it must have

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    include_once "emenikeconnect.php";

    $first = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconnection, $_POST["first"]);
    $last = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconnection, $_POST["last"]);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconnection, $_POST["email"]);
    $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconnection, $_POST["password"]);

    // Error handlers
    // Check for empty field

    if(empty($first) ||empty($last) ||empty($email) ||empty($pass)){
        die("Please this field is required");
         exit();
    }else{
        // Check if input character are valid
        if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/",$first)|| !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/",$last)){
            die("Firstname or Lastname have bad text");
            exit();
        }else{
            // Check if the email address is valid
            if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
                die("This email addres is invalid");
                exit();
            }else{
                // Hashing password
               $password = hash($pass);

                 // Insert data into database
               $querydata = "INSER INTO UserTable(ID, First-name, Last-name, Email, Password) VALUES ()";
               mysqli_query($dbconnection,$querydata);
               die("Register succesfullu");

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please explain expected behaviour and current behaviour (update your question)

Comment: @JonScott no need, read the query

Comment: Use parameterized queries instead of `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error on this line:

```
$querydata = "INSER INTO UserTable(ID, First-name, Last-name, Email, Password) VALUES ()";
```

You wrote `INSER` instead of `INSERT`. Also, you should have actual values in the `VALUES` clause, e.g. `VALUES(1, 'John', 'Smith', 'john.smith@example.com', 'secret')`.

On another note, rather use an ORM library that takes care of all the basics for you.